# problem with deleting some texts and then not being in chronological order

Tags: messages, ios

I have an iPhone 6. I clean up and only delete certain texts. When I do that the name and group of texts does not fall into the chronological line up, it stays at the top. Does that make sense? Why does it do that?

Comment: give us a sample

Comment: Sorted by last changed, I'd guess. Add a txt or delete one, both qualify as changed.

Answer (score 1):

Totally concur... On my old 4S, when I would delete some but not necessarily ALL of some messages in a conversation, that conversation would drop in my messages to its proper place, based on the date of the that last text.

With 6S, someone from 6 mos ago can send you a text.  After you reply and delete it, that message thread from 6 mos ago stays on top.

With the old 4S, they would drop down to their proper place based on date of last text.

That's a big bummer about the new iPhones versus the old ones.  And it makes it easy for something important to fall off the radar.

.